Ubuntu will work on my laptop?
Hey my laptop specs is i3-3120m and 2g ram and 128mb video memory
Will it start Ubuntu without lag or crashes?

The recommended minimum requirements for Ubuntu are listed at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements
You wrote that your system has 2G of RAM and 128MB of VRAM. The recommended minimums are 4G and 256MB.
It may be possible to install onto hardware with less than the minimum, but you may also encounter problems in use.
Whether or not YOUR system will encounter problems can only be determined with certainty by testing it.
